# Security Trimmings with MVCSiteMapProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

When using Security Trimmings with the MVCSiteMapProvider is there a way to hide a node when the user is authenticated, but show it when they are not authenticated (opposite to the way one normally uses it)?

Say I have a menu that shows Register, Sign-In, and Support.  When authenticated, I'd like it to hide Register and Sign-In, replacing with say, My Account, and then continue to show Support.  So, trying to stick with the Security Trimming features of the MVCSiteMapProvider, I'd like to hide a node when authenticated.

Thanks muchly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a custom visibility provider to hide the node when the user is authenticated. The MVC Music Store demo has [an example](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcMusicStore/Code/NonAuthenticatedVisibilityProvider.cs) of this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Only displays nodes when a user is not authenticated.
/// </summary>
public class NonAuthenticatedVisibilityProvider
    : SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderBase
{
    #region ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the node is visible.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="node">The node.</param>
    /// <param name="sourceMetadata">The source metadata.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <c>true</c> if the specified node is visible; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool IsVisible(ISiteMapNode node, IDictionary<string, object> sourceMetadata)
    {
        return !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You can call it by specifying the assembly type in the visibilityProvider property/attribute of the nodes you want to use it.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:SiteMapLocalizations,LogOnTitle" action="LogOn" visibilityProvider="MvcMusicStore.Code.NonAuthenticatedVisibilityProvider, Mvc Music Store" />
```